# What does a ! operator mean in front of a variable?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

I have just a simple question, I'm learning C programming and I know that the ! operator means logical NOT. My question is that what does it mean in this case in a do while cycle as a condition?
Is it checking somehow if the variable is changed?

I know I should probably find it somehow, but when I try to google '!'s it doesn't want to show what I meant.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input, ok=0;
    do {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if ( /* condition */) {
            //the input is wrong it will scan another one
        }
        else {
            //the input is correct, so the while cycle can stop
            //we don't need more inputs
            ok = 1;
        }
    } while (!ok);

    //...
    //...
    //...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Translation: `do {something} while (ok == 0);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!ok` is the same as `ok == 0`.

Remember that in C, *any* non-zero scalar value in a Boolean context means "true" while zero means "false".  It's a common C idiom to write `!foo` instead of `foo == 0`.  It works for pointers as well:

```
FILE *foo = fopen( "some_file", "r" );
if ( !foo )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "could not open some_file\n" );
  return EXIT_FAILURE; 
}
```

So, `while ( x )` is the same as `while ( x != 0 )`, and `while ( !x )` is the same as `while ( x == 0 )`.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking loosely, the given code executes the contents of the loop repeatedly "while NOT ok", meaning "while OK is zero". In the `else` block, `ok` is set to 1, meaning that the loop will not repeat again.

More formally, `!ok` is an expression that is true when `ok` is equal to zero, and false when `ok` is any value other than zero.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of logical operations, anything except zero (*) is `true`, zero is `false`.

so `!1` is "! true" is `false`
`!0` is "! false" is `true`

(*) any kind of zero: `NULL` counts as zero, `0.0` counts as zero

Answer (score 1):

Just think about it, the ok has a Boolean value, which is false at the initialisation.

(In c, 0 has a false value, I assume that you know this.)

In the do while, it is simply negates the logical value, it still means a NOT. If the condition is true, it will loop, otherwise, won't.

If ok has a false value and you'll negate it, it will have a true value, the loop will, umm loop.

I hope you'll get the point, it does not have any other meanings.